# Raw file in proxmox

Tags: virtual-machines, proxmox, import

I created a vm in proxmox. Now i need to use my astra.raw file. I saved raw file in /tmp.
How i can import my astra.raw file in VM?
I try to use  sudo qm importdisk 220 astra1.raw tmp and feetback was astra1.raw: non-existent or non-regular file

Comment: Are you asking how to copy a file into a VM?

Comment: how import VM in proxmox

Comment: So you have an existing VM that you want to import? What's the format of it? `raw` doesn't really tell us anything.